# Removing items from table

Tags: javascript

I'm solving this problem, I want to add and remove items to the HTML table using javascript. So far I've got this, but I don't really know how to make the removing part possible. Could you give me a hand please?

```
let inputJmeno = document.querySelector('#inputJmeno');
let inputPrijmeni = document.querySelector('#inputPrijmeni');
let inputVek = document.querySelector('#inputVek');
let buttonAdd = document.querySelector('#add');

let table = document.querySelector('table');
let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
let tr = document.querySelector('tr');

let jmeno = null;
let prijmeni = null;
let vek = null;
let pocetOsob = 0;

buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', add);

function add() {
    jmeno = inputJmeno.value;
    prijmeni = inputPrijmeni.value;
    vek = inputVek.value;

    let newRow = document.createElement('tr');
    let newJmeno = document.createElement('td');
    let newPrijmeni = document.createElement('td');
    let newVek = document.createElement('td');
    let krizek = document.createElement('span');

    krizek.id = "krizek" + pocetOsob;
    krizek.className = "krizClass";
    newRow.id = "row" + pocetOsob;

    newJmeno.innerHTML = jmeno;
    newPrijmeni.innerHTML = prijmeni;
    newVek.innerHTML = vek;
    krizek.innerHTML = 'x';

    tbody.appendChild(newRow);
    newRow.appendChild(newJmeno);
    newRow.appendChild(newPrijmeni);
    newRow.appendChild(newVek);
    newRow.appendChild(krizek);

    load(pocetOsob);
    pocetOsob++;
}

    function load(p) {
        let krz = document.querySelector('#krizek'+p);
    console.log(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
newRow.removeChild(krizek);
```